# Cacti showing white screen when I click finish while installing cacti for the first time

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apache-2.4, cacti

I am installing cacti on my ubuntu server following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/installing-the-cacti-server-monitor-on-ubuntu-12-04-cloud-server) tutorial

When I visit, **mydomain/cacti**, I was redirected to **mydomain/cacti/install** where I chose **new install** and after that I got redirected to **mydomain/cacti/install/index.php** where all the fields are automatically set and are indicated to be ok.

However when I click finish to submit the form, a white screen is displayed and the url still remains mydomain/cacti/install/index.php**

I can't figure what I have done wrongly

My apache2 error log indicates the following

```
[Thu Jul 10 12:05:28.799595 2014] [:error] [pid 28811] [client 41.87.105.66:37695] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function session_unregister() in /usr/share/cacti/site/lib/functions.php on line 408, referer: mydomain/cacti/install/index.php
[Thu Jul 10 12:05:28.799622 2014] [:error] [pid 28811] [client 41.87.105.66:37695] PHP Stack trace:, referer: mydomain/cacti/install/index.php
[Thu Jul 10 12:05:28.799633 2014] [:error] [pid 28811] [client 41.87.105.66:37695] PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/cacti/site/install/index.php:0, referer: mydomain/cacti/install/index.php
[Thu Jul 10 12:05:28.799643 2014] [:error] [pid 28811] [client 41.87.105.66:37695] PHP   2. kill_session_var() /usr/share/cacti/site/install/index.php:347, referer: mydomain/cacti/install/index.php
```

Comment: Any log file entries, e.g. in the Apache logs? Permissions for JavaScript and Cookies etc. whitelisted?

Comment: from the chrome developer tools, I can see that the css and js files are loading correctly but the index.php file is returning a 500 status

Comment: @SvW I have just uploaded the output from the apache error log above

Comment: Apperantly the session_unregister() function is deprecated on php5 so all I had to do was comment out that line 408 which refers to that and all is well